# Saving multiple plots on a single pdf page using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to save the graphs of all 11 sectors from sectorlist to 1 pdf sheet. So far the code below gives me a graph on a separate sheet (11 pdf pages).

The daily return functions is the data I'm plotting. There are 2 lines on each graph.

```
with PdfPages('test.pdf') as pdf:
n=0
for i in sectorlist:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    n+=1
    fig.add_subplot(4,3,n)
    (daily_return[i]*100).plot(linewidth=3)
    (daily_return['^OEX']*100).plot()
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylabel('Excess movement (%)')
    plt.xticks(rotation='45')
    pdf.savefig(fig)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if your indentation is wrong just in your question, but the key is you need to finish plotting all subplots before save your fig as pdf. Specifically, you need to move `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))` and `pdf.savefig(fig)` outside your `for` loop and keep them within your `with` statement. Here is one example modified from yours, which gives you 1 pdf page with 11 subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import numpy as np

with PdfPages('test.pdf') as pdf:
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
    s = s * 50

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    n=0
    for i in range(11):
        n += 1
        ax = fig.add_subplot(4,3,n)
        ax.plot(t, s, linewidth=3, label='a')
        ax.plot(t, s / 2, linewidth=3, label='b')
        ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        ax.legend()
        ax.yaxis.set_label_text('Excess movement (%)')
        plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels(), rotation='45')
    pdf.savefig(fig)
```

Comment: also my data has a 63 day lag (bc of rolling average),where the first 63 days are empty values (hence empty on the graph). do you know how to get rid of this?

Comment: @thomas.mac What do you mean by "get rid of"? `NaN` won't be plotted. If you worried about the `xlim`, one suggestion (though I'm not sure if it's the best) will be to use [`pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index) to find out the first `NaN`. Then change `xlim` accordingly.

Comment: my graph starts halfway, as in the left side is completely empty, only the right half is graphing

Comment: @thomas.mac That's from the auto setting of x-axis range. As I said, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index` first to find out the first non-NaN value. Then you can either change `xlim` accordingly or trim you `DataFrame` accordingly. For `Series`, you have [`pandas.Series.first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.first_valid_index).